# spring-data-redis with cacheManager

Tags: redis, spring-cache, spring-data-redis

When I use spring-data-redis, it across two problems.

The First problem is when I use cache annation to load data to redis, but I can not get the value by redisTemplate, the code as flows :

```
@Bean
RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {

    JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHostName("localhost");
    factory.setPort(6379);
    factory.setUsePool(true);

    return factory;
}

@Bean
CacheManager cacheManager() {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate());
    cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(86400);
    return cacheManager;
}
```

UserService as flows :

```
@Cacheable("allUsers")
public List<UserModel> getAllUsers() {
    logger.info("execute getAllUsers!");
    return Arrays.asList(new UserModel("jason"), new UserModel("david"));
}
```

my test code is :

```
@Test
public void testCache() {
    redisTemplate.delete("allUsers");

    userService.getAllUsers();  // load user data
    List<Object> users = redisTemplate.opsForList().range("allUsers", 0, -1); // get allUsers from redis

    logger.info("get from template");
    for(Object user : users) {
        logger.info(((UserModel)user).getUsername());
    }

    logger.info("get from service");
    for(UserModel user : userService.getAllUsers()) {
        logger.info(user.getUsername());
    }
```

and , I found the cache "allUsers" in redis is allUsers~keys, but I also can not get value by this key, how can I get the value by redisTemplate and why the key is allUsers~keys in redis.

The second problem is I set a key call "mykey" by commond , and set value "mykey", and I also cant get null value by java code , I can get value through commond. How is that?
If the two problems are the same one?
Is anyone know these? Thank you advance ^.^ .

update my code version is :
spring   4.1.6,
spring-data-redis 1.7.0,
Jedis 2.8.1
redis 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Initializing the `RedisTemplate` without a `RedisSerializer` defaults the template to use the `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer`. So the key produced will not be the plain `String` value but rather something like `\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x0bcache-key-1`.

You can use the `StringRedisSerializer` as `keySerializer` to have plain `String` keys.

```java
RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
```